# MultipleBeansException when building GeoServer Docker image(2.23.2) with community plugins jdbcconfig,jms-cluster

Tags: docker, geoserver

I encountered MultipleBeansException an issue when building GeoServer docker image, version: 2.23.x
The error message is the following:

```
22 Sep 11:23:50 WARN   [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServerLoader' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.75/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.23-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.config.GeoServerLoader
```

The run command i used is:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,src=/home/milos/GeoServer,target=/opt/geoserver_data   -it -p8080:8080   --env INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true   --env STABLE_EXTENSIONS="pyramid"   --env COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS="jdbcconfig,jms-cluster"   docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.23.x
```

Before executing the docker run command, folder /home/milos/GeoServer exists and it is empty.
Is this a bug, or it isn't expected that these two plugins work together?
If i install jms-cluster plugin without jdbcconfig, docker run executes normally...

Answer (score 0):

They are both clustering plugins, only one of them should be used, an installation with both does not make sense, not surprising that it does not start, they both offer an alternative catalog implementation.

Comment: I did not understand that from the docs: https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/community/jdbcconfig/index.html 
So in case when i need real time synchronization, i should go with jms-clustering? Meaning jdbcconfig does not offer realtime synchronization between nodes in a cluster?

Comment: They both offer the same functionality. You have to choose one or the other. They are both community plugins, thus, both unsupported.